# Find the closest paths to each other?

Tags: graphics, path

I have set of paths which starts from same point but moves in different direction. I have another path called original path which also start from same point. All these paths are in 2-D i.e. I have (x,y) values. I need to find out the closest path (among the set of paths) to the original path. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the length of the paths you can use an A* algorithm. You did not mention any programming language nor shown some relevant code. That way i could give you a more detailed answer.

Edit:

I think the solution is to simplify the problem like this:

What if you got a class Square with a method that returns true if a point is inside this square (is fairly easy to program and should work efficient). You put 3 rather big of these squares on the orignial path.
Then you iterate trough all points of the selectable paths and check if all squares are hit by this path. if they are you add them to another list for the next recursion. if all paths are iterated through you check whether only 1 path hits all the squares (is the solution) you return it. if more than 1 paths hits all squares you enter the next recursion with 2ce the squares and half sidelength. if no path hits all squares you increase the sidelength by 25% for the next recursion an put all paths of this recursion into the next. As less and less paths have to be checked this should have a pretty good performance.

Comment: Programming language - C++
All paths are saved in array with each path contains 50 points.

Comment: Did you look at A*? A searchnode could be only a reference to a patharray with an index. expanding the node would mean you advance the index by one. the heuristic would be distance from goal + distance allready travelled.

Comment: If there are intersections between the paths you can divide the paths into pathchunks having the ideal graph for A* of course expanding the node means that you have more than one node in that case

Comment: You can look here for detail description of problem (with diagram)
---http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=82770

Comment: So you need this stuff for an ai-algorithm? as in computer games?

Comment: I need it for some sort of animation where path is drawn on ground and character need to follow that path. Character is pre-loaded with that set of other paths(shown in color in the [image](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=82770)).

Comment: @omkar1707 added a theoretical solution.